# A box contains 5 yellow and 3 red balls, from which 4 balls are drawn one at a time, at random, without replacement.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A box contains 5 yellow and 3 red balls, from which 4 balls are drawn one at a time, at random, without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of yellow balls on the first two draws and $Y$ the number of yellow balls on all 4 draws.

Find the joint probability function, $f(x,y)$.

The solution is

${5 \choose x}$$3 \choose 2-x$$5-x \choose y-x$$1+x \choose 2+x-y$
/ $8 \choose 2$$6 \choose 2$

I have no idea how they got solution.
Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For all the possible values of $x$ and $y$, we want to calculate $f(x,y)=\Pr((X=x)\cap(Y=y))$. For example, the probability that $X=1$ and $Y=3$ is $(2)(5/8)(3/7)(4/6)(3/5)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider each ball to be identifiable, although we are mainly interested in
whether the ball is yellow.

We start with $8$ balls. The first draw chooses $2$ of them.
There are $\binom 82$ possible pairs of balls that we can draw on the first draw.

For each possible pair of balls that we draw first, 
there is a set of $6$ balls remaining to draw from.
There are $\binom 62$ possible pairs of balls that can be drawn from this set of $6.$

So, $\binom 82$ possible first pairs, and for each of these, $\binom 62$ possible second
pairs, a total of $\binom 82 \binom 62$ equally likely outcomes of the two draws.

We now count how many of those outcomes had $x$ yellow balls in the first pair
and $y$ yellow balls among all four balls drawn.

The first draw choose $x$ balls from among the $5$ yellow balls, which can happen
in $\binom 5x$ different ways,
and the remaining $2-x$ balls from the other $3$ balls,
which can happen in $\binom 3{2-x}$ ways.

After drawing those $x$ yellow balls and $2-x$ red balls, we have
$5-x$ yellow balls and $1+x$ red balls remaining.
We draw $y-x$ yellow balls from the set of $5-x,$
which can happen in $\binom{5-x}{y-x}$ ways.
Notice that we now have identified $x + (2-x) + (y-x)$ of the $4$ balls that
are drawn; $4 - (x + (2-x) + (y-x)) = 2 + x - y,$ so that is the number of
red balls that must be drawn on the second draw.
There are $\binom{1+x}{2 + x - y}$ ways to draw that number of red balls
from the remaining $1+x$ red balls.

Note that for each way to choose the first $x$ yellow balls, there are the same
number of ways to choose the first $2-x$ red balls, and then the same number
of ways to choose the next $y-x$ yellow balls, and finally for every way we
can get to this point there are the same number of ways to choose the last
$2+x-y$ red balls. 
(Note that we are not choosing from the same *set* of balls in each case in the
last two enumerations of choices, but in each case the *number of ways* 
we can get the desired outcome is the same.)
The total number of ways to draw $x$ yellow balls on the first
draw and $y$ yellow balls total is therefore the product of all the numbers
of options we had for each choice:
$$ \binom 5x \binom 3{2-x} \binom{5-x}{y-x} \binom{1+x}{2 + x - y}.$$
That is the number of "successful" $(x,y)$ outcomes among the
$\binom 82 \binom 62$ equally likely outcomes, so we divide by $\binom 82 \binom 62$
to get the probability.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ takes 3 possible values and $Y$ takes 5 possible values, so $f(x,y)$ must be defined on 15 pairs of points $(x,y)$. My suggestion is that you start simply computing some of them. I think you will notice that alot of them are easy to compute since they are either zero or can be phrased into a question about $Y$ solely. For example, $f(1,0)=f(2,0)=0$. $f(0,0)=P(Y=0)$. etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative way to compute $P(X,Y)$.

---

The following table depicts the probability of each drawing-sequence:

```
 Draw #1 | Draw #2 | Draw #3 | Draw #4 | X,Y | Probability
---------|---------|---------|---------|-----|------------------------------
 Red     | Red     | Red     | Yellow  | 0,1 | 3/8 * 2/7 * 1/6 * 5/5 = 1/56
 Red     | Red     | Yellow  | Red     | 0,1 | 3/8 * 2/7 * 5/6 * 1/5 = 1/56
 Red     | Red     | Yellow  | Yellow  | 0,2 | 3/8 * 2/7 * 5/6 * 4/5 = 4/56
 Red     | Yellow  | Red     | Red     | 1,1 | 3/8 * 5/7 * 2/6 * 1/5 = 1/56
 Red     | Yellow  | Red     | Yellow  | 1,2 | 3/8 * 5/7 * 2/6 * 4/5 = 4/56
 Red     | Yellow  | Yellow  | Red     | 1,2 | 3/8 * 5/7 * 4/6 * 2/5 = 4/56
 Red     | Yellow  | Yellow  | Yellow  | 1,3 | 3/8 * 5/7 * 4/6 * 3/5 = 6/56
 Yellow  | Red     | Red     | Red     | 1,1 | 5/8 * 3/7 * 2/6 * 1/5 = 1/56
 Yellow  | Red     | Red     | Yellow  | 1,2 | 5/8 * 3/7 * 2/6 * 4/5 = 4/56
 Yellow  | Red     | Yellow  | Red     | 1,2 | 5/8 * 3/7 * 4/6 * 2/5 = 4/56
 Yellow  | Red     | Yellow  | Yellow  | 1,3 | 5/8 * 3/7 * 4/6 * 3/5 = 6/56
 Yellow  | Yellow  | Red     | Red     | 2,2 | 5/8 * 4/7 * 3/6 * 2/5 = 4/56
 Yellow  | Yellow  | Red     | Yellow  | 2,3 | 5/8 * 4/7 * 3/6 * 3/5 = 6/56
 Yellow  | Yellow  | Yellow  | Red     | 2,3 | 5/8 * 4/7 * 3/6 * 3/5 = 6/56
 Yellow  | Yellow  | Yellow  | Yellow  | 2,4 | 5/8 * 4/7 * 3/6 * 2/5 = 4/56
```

You can verify that the sum of the probabilities is indeed $1$.

---

Then, you can add up identical combinations of $X$ and $Y$ in order to compute $P(X,Y)$:

- $P(0,1)=\frac{2}{56}$
- $P(0,2)=\frac{4}{56}$
- $P(1,1)=\frac{2}{56}$
- $P(1,2)=\frac{16}{56}$
- $P(1,3)=\frac{12}{56}$
- $P(2,2)=\frac{4}{56}$
- $P(2,3)=\frac{12}{56}$
- $P(2,4)=\frac{4}{56}$